# In co-op what level matters for farm effects?

Tags: stardew-valley

[image]

If I'm playing the Hilltop farm in co-op - what farmer's mining level is used for the hilltop spawns?

Answer (score 1):

Though it isn't explicitly mentioned on the wiki (at least not that I could find), your best bet would be to go off the mining level of the **host** (the person who created the farm). Other players might have an effect on it, though I'm not sure.